# SQL Alchemy maps UUID-primary key to string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, uuid, sqlmodel

I'm working with SQLModel and I created following base-table and table:

```py
class GUIDModel(PydanticBase):
    """
    Provides a base mixin for tables with GUID as primary key
    """

    guid: Optional[UUID] = Field(
        ...,
        primary_key=True,
        description=DescriptionConstants.GUID,
        sa_column=Column(
            "guid",
            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            nullable=False,
            primary_key=True,
            server_default=text("newsequentialid()"),
        ),
    )

class Project(GUIDModel):
    name: str = Field(max_length=255, description=DescriptionConstants.NAME)
```

So everything works, but when I try to get a row with SQL Alchemy, it returns the GUID as a string instead of UUID

```py
def test_get_project(self):
    with Session(__get_engine()) as session:
        project: Project = Projects._get_project(session)
        self.assertEqual(type(project.guid), uuid.UUID)
```

Error:

```
<class 'uuid.UUID'> != <class 'str'>
Expected :<class 'str'>
Actual   :<class 'uuid.UUID'>
<Click to see difference>
```

Comment: What dialect and driver are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson using SQL Server with `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using vanilla SQLAlchemy ORM. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/c44845636383770478573cefb7fa3e86) works for me.

Comment: @GordThompson `SQLModel` uses `SQLAlchemy 1.4.41`. I just tested your code with SA v2.0.9 and it works perfect - with SA v1.4.41 it returns a str instead of UUID. So this might be the problem..

Comment: Ah, okay, then maybe you can use a type decorator [something like this](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/f8a71ca7a447dfe1949de2c477b05291).

Comment: @GordThompson I figured out, SQLModel has a new version released a few weeks ago that's enabling support for SQLAlchemy v2. So just trying to update it. Thanks for your help :)